# Java - Collision detection (glitch)

Tags: java, collision-detection

I am working on a platformer game for the final year project in HS.
However... The collision detection system I use is basically about checking wether a specific part of the character intersects with another block or not.

The collision seems to be working fine except that it causes some bugs such as player kind of getting stuck or slowing down when hitting from the sides or gets thrown up when both upper and < or > keys are used.

**My question is; How can I improve the collision code in order to avoid such glitches and have sort of 'slippery' collisions?**

This is the kind of collision effect that I am trying to achieve:
(https://i.imgur.com/KB1M3bt.mp4)
[image]

(https://i.imgur.com/I44fmPc.mp4)
[image]

here is a preview of how the bounds look

[image]

and here is a preview of what it actually looks like in game
([click for better quality](https://i.imgur.com/vosg4K3.mp4))
[image]

The code i use for collision detection:
(tempObject are blocks that the player is intersecting with)

```
if(getBoundsTop().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsBottom())){
    y = tempObject.getY() + height;
    velY = 0;
    System.out.println("Top collision");
}

if(getBoundsBottom().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsTop())){
    y = tempObject.getY() - height;
    velY = 0;
    falling = false;
    jumping = false;
    //isOnBlock = true;
} else {
    falling = true;
    //isOnBlock = false;
}

if(getBoundsRight().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsLeft())){
    x = tempObject.getX() - this.width;
}


if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsRight())){
    x = tempObject.getX() + this.width;
}
```

and here are the bound methods:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() { return new Rectangle( (int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height ); }

    public Rectangle getBoundsTop() {
        return new Rectangle(
                (int)x, 
                (int)y, 
                (int)(width-(width*0.01f)), 
                (int)(height/2)
        );
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsBottom() {
        return new Rectangle(
                (int)x,
                (int)(y+(height/2)),
                (int)(width-(width*0.01f)),
                (int)(height/2)
        );
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundsLeft() {
        return new Rectangle(
                (int)x,
                (int)y, 
                (int)((int)width*0.15f), 
                (int)height
        );
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundsRight() {
        return new Rectangle(
                (int) 
                ((int)x+(width-(width*0.15f))), 
                (int)y, 
                (int) ((int)width*0.15f), 
                (int)height
        );
    }
```

Edit: Im using a constant acceleration speed for setting velocity

```
acc = 2.5f;
MAX_SPEED = 10;


if(Game.keyDownMap.containsKey(KeyEvent.VK_A)){

    setVelX(getVelX() - acc);
    if(getVelX() < -MAX_SPEED)
        setVelX(-MAX_SPEED);

} else if(Game.keyDownMap.containsKey(KeyEvent.VK_D)){

    setVelX(getVelX() + acc);
    if(getVelX() > MAX_SPEED)
        setVelX(MAX_SPEED);

}
```

Comment: very well asked! (+1) : you provided a well explained problem with both images/animations on site and a detailed and well formated code example. This should be used as a template for referencing when writing new questions, IMHO.

Comment: Well, you first want to define what do you want to happen when a collission with a wall is happening. Do you want to do wall jumping like mario/prince of persia? do you want a sharp drop? do you want a slide down the wall? what do you want to happen on a sideways collision?

Comment: Looking at the animation, I see that the block keeps moving when its collided with an object. In these cases you probably want to stop it moving in a given direction once its collided, but not reset the position. Try and adjust where you check for a collision and where you change the characters position. Also if you want smoother movements, you can add acceleration instead of changing the velocity straight away. This will make the movements a bit smoother, but you will need to adjust it to suit your purposes.

Comment: @Tschallacka I've updated the question now. :)

Comment: What do you use for velocity? can you post that part of the code?

Comment: @Tschallacka Updated the post

Comment: Your are not setting `velX` to 0 when detecting a horizontal collision.

Comment: I just set that to 0 and i noticed something else; When i am at maximum speed and try to hit a block, i walk trough it :D (doesn't always happen)

Answer (score 1):

When there's a sidewards collision, you want to set your sidewards velocity to zero. That way there can only be a vertical velocity, which I assume will be setVelY();

```
if(getBoundsRight().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsLeft())){
    x = tempObject.getX() - this.width;
    setVelX(0);
}


if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsRight())){
    x = tempObject.getX() + this.width;
    setVelX(0);
}
```

Also you need to check on key down if there's no collision status active. You'll probably want to make a method to set if it's currently intersecting with something which you update every gametick.

```
if(Game.keyDownMap.containsKey(KeyEvent.VK_A) && !isIntersectingLeft()){

    setVelX(getVelX() - acc);
    if(getVelX() < -MAX_SPEED)
        setVelX(-MAX_SPEED);

} else if(Game.keyDownMap.containsKey(KeyEvent.VK_D) && !isIntersectingRight()){

    setVelX(getVelX() + acc);
    if(getVelX() > MAX_SPEED)
        setVelX(MAX_SPEED);

}
```

if you want a little bounce you could set a little velocity in the different direction.

```
if(getBoundsRight().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsLeft())){
    x = tempObject.getX() - this.width;
    if(this.getVelX() > 0) {
        setVelX(10);
    }
}


if(getBoundsLeft().intersects(tempObject.getBoundsRight())){
    x = tempObject.getX() + this.width;
    if(this.getVelX() > 0) {
       setVelX(-10);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems to be working better than before :D I guess I will have to play around with the side bounds to avoid player getting thrown away when they hit blocks with a corner

Comment: what you can do is use multiple bounding boxes. You have one big bounding box that wraps around all smaller bb's. If the big one is collided, then you iterate the smaller sets of bb's in that big bounding box to see if there's a "true" collision. That way you can incoperate round and triangle features.

Comment: yes. If the player collides with green box, iterate the red boxes to check collision, then iterate yellow boxes to iterate collision. You don't need the hitboxes in the center though, you only need those on the outermost edges.